# Elastic Beanstalk worker environment daemon grace period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, daemon

I have a beanstalk worker environment, it runs tasks that can cost a few dollars for me to run per task, so I don't want the tasks to be interrupted.

The two interruptions I am worried about are updates, and scaling down events. In each of these cases, I know that the daemon receives a shutdown signal, and then has a 60 second (I believe, I have not verified this) period to allow any outstanding daemon-server connections to resolve.

The behavior I would like is for the daemon to hold off until any daemon-server connection has timed out, or resolved.

For the life of me, I can't find how to edit this part of the daemon... even if it were to be changing the grace period to be equal to the timeout length, that would be acceptable, but I can't find how to go about doing this.

I would really love to use beanstalk due to all the other nice things it has baked in, so any help would be greatly appreciated.